# Gradle multiproject build - main class name has not been configured

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, java-11

I have build a gradle multiproject with the following structure (gradle -q projects):

**- Root project 'project-root'**

```
 build.gradle
 
 settings.gradle
```

**+.......project 'project-a-no-springboot'**

```
 build.gradle
```

**+.......project 'project-b-springbootrestapi'**

```
 build.gradle: This implements project-a-no-springboot as a dependency
```

I can run the project-b-springbootrestapi without problems and the API works fine, but when I try to build project-a or project-b the build fails.

- **build root project-a build error**: Error while evaluating property 'mainClass' of task
- **build root project-b build error**: Caused by:.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660

I need to build the project because I need to use the libs to create a Docker image.

Many thanks